# verbouse assertions with Test::Unit (minitest?) in ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testunit, minitest

I'm in the middle of the upgrade of my application. I want to move from ruby 1.8 to 1.9 and from rails 3.0 to 3.2 (right now I run ruby 1.9 and RoR 3.2). I have problems with my tests: the output is vague and not very helpful. For example for `assert_difference` I get:

```
Failure:
test_should_create_new_version_if_versioning_needed_and_diaconies_changed(AnimatorProfilesControllerTest)
test/functional/animator_profiles_controller_test.rb:108:in `block in <class:SomeTest>'
  => 108:     assert_difference('SomeModel.count', 1) do
     109:       put :update, :id => @model.to_param, :model => attrs 
     110:     end
     111: 
<> expected but was
<>

diff:
  nil
```

The problems is that there is no diff (as you can see). The other problem is that when I have a message in assert, it is not shown when it fails. How could I fix it?

Comment: What version of minitest are you using? Try upgrading to the latest gem. The objects being compared are likely different, even if they don't appear different in the output message. Newer minitest releases make this much clearer.

Comment: Appeared that I didn't have minitest in the Gemfile. Now it's OK, thanks.